# Selecting points inside polygon using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select-by-location, donut-polygons

I have a points layer and a polygon layer. They are overlapping.

How do I select all points within the polygon including those inside but not overlapped (see yellow color in the picture below)?

[image]

Comment: From your picture it looks like you what you are asking is how to also select features within the gaps of a donut polygon.

Comment: You are right @PolyGeo.

Comment: You could write that up as an answer of a few paragraphs, and potentially earn some reputation to help unlock site features for you.

Answer (score 1):

I used a tool "eliminate polygon part (data management)". This tool will fill the gaps inside the donut polygon and generate a complete polygon. Then, I made "select by location" using the new polygon.